# Cloudera sqoop mapping certain columns to null values on import

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop

What would be the best way to convert some columns to be just null placeholders on the import?

Would it be possible to use the map-column feature?

```
Argument    Description
--map-column-java <mapping> Override mapping from SQL to Java type for configured columns.
--map-column-hive <mapping> Override mapping from SQL to Hive type for configured columns.
```

We want the schema to be identical but some columns just hold a lot of bloat so we do not want them pulled into our cluster. 
The other thought is to generate custom select statements where bloated columns are null but that is a lot more configuration of sqoop and we have a thousand tables to map.

```
--map-column-java bloatedcolname=null
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--query` fro this

For example:

```
sqoop import --query 'select a, b, null as c, null as d from tbl where $CONDITIONS'
```

`$CONDITIONS` is used to substitute min and max values for split.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `--columns <col1, col2, col3…>` in your hive import query.

*Exclude columns that you don't want to import.*

---

**Example:**

I have four columns in RDBMS - id, name, occupation, address and I want to import only id and name.

Use `--columns id, name` in your import command.

Comment: The above does not work and the scheme it will not be identical. In Hive the columns will not line up and it becomes a big pain for the subsequent processing.

Comment: @Chris Don't create hive table using sqoop. Use same Hive table you created using previous command.

Comment: I tried that, but it fills it from left to right. If you don't include the first  column, the values are in the wrong columns!